# Pass parameter from build step to post-build step in Jenkins

Tags: parameters, jenkins, post-build

How can I pass a parameter in Jenkins from a **build** step to **post-build** step?
I don't want to do it through a file, as it's just a simple string (version number) that I want to pass.

In post-build I use Groovy postbuild plugin to add this string to the summary of the build.

**Update:**
I was in despair )) and decided to go via file route.
Couldn't figure out how to get WORKSPACE env var in Groovy post-build step to get file from there.

**Final update:**
So I ended up parsing build log, see my own answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up printing information to the build log in the **build** step, and then parsing it in the **post-build** Groovy plugin.

A bit ugly workaround, I know, sometimes I miss TeamCity with it's simplicity...

Regex pattern below is obviously specific to my own build...

```
def matcher = manager.getLogMatcher("^Build Found:  [\\w\\s-]+_(\\d+\\.\\d+\\.\\d+)_\\d{8}(\\.\\d+)?\$")
if (matcher?.matches()) {
    def Version = matcher.group(1)
    manager.addShortText(Version, "grey", "white", "0px", "white")
    manager.createSummary("fingerprint.gif").appendText("Version: " + Version, false)
} else {
    manager.listener.logger.println("ERROR: Version number is not found in the build log")
    manager.buildFailure()
}
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing your solution. The EnvInject plugin didn't work for my use-case, wherein I need to export an environment variable when the build fails. When the build fails, the EnvInject build steps is simply not called at all - probably a bug. I am using your solution to export an environment variable in the PostBuild Groovy Step. This environment variable is then picked up by another post-build step (email-ext plugin). Life-saver :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe using the [envinject plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/EnvInject+Plugin) ?

Comment: that should do it through a file

Comment: Thanks, coffeebreaks! I've tried it. First, it looked promising - adding a build step of type "Inject environment varialbes" which states that it will "Inject environment variables to the following build steps and post-build actions." Then I couldn't figure out how to get that env var in the post-build Groovy step... Thanks, anyway!

Comment: Did you get any solution for this?